# How to disable onkeyup for a few seconds

Tags: javascript, php

im creating a browser game and i have added keybinds so the player can use keys to move around the world.
If people use the buttons to move, these buttons are getting hidden for 5 seconds to allow an animation to end. Now i want to do this for the keybinds too.
For example: Player presses spacebar and a interval will run that lasts 5 seconds. Pressing space again will glitch out really bad running the same interval twice. So how do i disable a function for 5 seconds after it has been called so that it won't glitch out?

This is the code i use for the keys:

```
<script>
            document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
                if(e.keyCode == 32){
                    var cmd = "<?php echo $row['HEADING']; ?>";
                    if(cmd == "N") myMoveUp();
                    if(cmd == "E") myMoveRight();
                    if(cmd == "S") myMoveDown();
                    if(cmd == "W") myMoveLeft();
                }
                if(e.keyCode == 37){
                    ChangeHeadingKP("W");  
                }
                if(e.keyCode == 38){
                    ChangeHeadingKP("N");  
                }
                if(e.keyCode == 39){
                    ChangeHeadingKP("E");  
                }
                if(e.keyCode == 40){
                    ChangeHeadingKP("S");  
                }
            }
            </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on timing (say, 5 seconds) because when you change them, you'll have to review your code.

Instead I'd rely on toggling a flag by calling specific methods, like this:

```
keymanager.suspend();
// play animation, cutscene or whatever
keymanager.resume();
```

Those two functions are easy to define, along with the `keymanager`, as follows:

```
var keymanager = {
  "active": true,
  "suspend": () => {
    keymanager.active = false;
  },
  "resume": () => {
    keymanager.active = true;
  }
};
```

All that remains is the key event handler bailing out when keys are deactivated:

```
document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {

  if (!keymanager.active)
  {
    return; // do not process any keys
  }

  // rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: Wonderful. I've been trying this for 2 days and you fixed it for me in a few minutes:) Really appreciated.